# eaccelerator.cache_dir with vhosts

Tags: php

What is the best solution to store the cach files? One directory for all or explicit directorys for each running vhost? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have huge amounts of vhosts, from the performance point of view it should not matter.

From the security point of view the separate directories might be a better option than a single directory, depending on your web server setup. If every vhost does use its own user-id (instead of running everything as Apache user), the separate directories are definitely a better option.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being unhelpful, have you considered using APC, instead?

Comment: no ;) We eAcclerator is preinstalled